# nginx reverse proxy Angular Node app mixed content http requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ssl, nginx

I'm dealing with nginx and node express server, the app used to works fine with reverse proxy over port 80 but the issue started when i installed a SSL with certbot over nginx, i've been trying also with https node module but i'm still getting mixed content error when i make requests from my angular front to my node backend. I think it's a bad traffic configuration over nginx, maybe i need to set traffic from nginx to node server (port 3000) with http but i'm not sure how to achieve that. Thanks in advance.

Console error when requests:

polyfills-es2015.aa82454585d558e1759e.js:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.example.com/signup' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://myVpsIpNumber:3000/api/register'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is my nginx set:

```
server {

   server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

my express server:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

let app = express();

//routes
const user_routes = require('./routes/user.router');

// middlewares
app.use(cors());

app.use(('/'), express.static('client', {redirect: false}));
app.use('/api', user_routes);

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('client/index.html'));
})


// start server
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started at port : 3000'));
```

Angular service:

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True' }) };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  postUser(user: User){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api' + '/register', user, this.noAuthHeader);
 }
```

node backend:

```js
register: (req, res, next) => {
        let user = new User();
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.password = req.body.password;
    
        user.save((err, doc) => {
            if (!err)
                res.send(doc);
            else {
                if (err.code == 11000)
                    res.status(422).send(['Email ya registrado']);
                else
                    return next(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: `I think it's a bad traffic configuration over nginx` ... no, the error is in the web page itself - the only thing you haven't shown ... somewhere you're trying to request a resource over `http` which is forbidden when the page is loaded `https` - exactly as the error is stating ... note `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;` is fine and not the source of the error

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The web page works fine on browser with my vps ip and port 3000 directly, and http requests also works. The issue is when i go to my domain, the page loads but throws that mixed content error.

Comment: yes ... because if you load the page using https you can't then use http for other resources/requests

Comment: I added angular y node snippets, i read about it's possible to make internal server traffic by http from my front to my backend, but i'm not sure

Comment: if your page is served using https, then `this.http.post(http://localhost:3000/api` will fail - change it to `this.http.post(https://localhost:3000/api` (3rd time I've said the same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in API calls from frontend, the solution is replacing the URL with the SSL domain (using https://).

> Development:

```js
'http://localhost:3000'
```

> Production:

```js
'https://www.example.com'
```

```js
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True' }) };

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

postUser(user: User){
  return this.http.post('https://www.example.com/api' + '/register', user, this.noAuthHeader);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue although not with Angular but Vuejs. With http everything worked fine but after installing SSL certificate with certbot I got the "mixed content" error.  I'm a beginner and  couldn't figure out how to have my frontend talk to backend. It took me quite a while to solve this, so I hope this helps:

1. Copy your "dist" folder in which you store your production build in this directory /var/www/html like so
   `$ cp -r /usr/src/app/dist/* /var/www/html`
2. Nginx default file at /etc/nginx/sites-available/default should look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name www.example.com example.com; # managed by Certbot


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }


location /api {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; 
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.example.com example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

3. In frontend use `https://example.com/api` instead of `http://localhost:3000/api` like so (not sure if this is working in Angular exactly like this, but you get the point):

```
postUser(user: User){
    return this.http.post('https://example.com/api' + '/register', user, this.noAuthHeader);
 }
```

4. app.js file looks ok. So no changes should be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Docker container to host your frontend, make sure that your docker container pulls and uses the latest Docker image with the updated version for apiUrl (e.g., https://example.com/api).